# Enable scrolling touch IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, mobile, touch

In my site i have this problem:

I want that all pages is scrollable if the device have a touch display. My site run into IE

I try with apply `touch-action pan-y` on my principal div but no result.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to scroll a webpage in IE 11 on a touch screen? It seems that we can scroll webpages directly in browsers in a touch screen. Is the problem only occurs in IE? What kind of device are you using? Is there any error in console in IE? Could you please provide a minimal sample which can reproduce the issue?

Comment: My problem is that i have browser mode=IE8 so i think that is impossible...

Comment: In my test, the page can be touched to scroll directly on a touch screen even without `touch-action`. From [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=touch-action), we can see that `touch-action` is supported by IE since IE 10. So it won't work in IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

Add style to head of your html document

```
<style>.tst{overflow: hidden;}</style>

Add this line in body tag
<body  class="tst" onload ="NoScroll()">

//content here
```

Add this inside script tags

```
function noScroll() {
var page = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
console.log("touch device detected");
page.classList.remove("tst");
}
else{
console.log("desktop mode");
page.classList.add("tst");
}  
}
```

Comment: i want only that all page scrolling on touch.